# Select em multiplas colunas com ponto no nome não retorna resultado

Tags: php, mysql

Cada coluna é composta de nomes, Fulano, Ciclano, Beltrano etc.. Quero selecionar todos os nomes que sejam diferentes. Se existir Joaquim em duas colunas tem que me retornar um só. Mas o problema não está ai, está no nome das colunas que contém ponto col.A col.B col.C Não sei se isso é permitido, não li nada contra mas o caso é que não funfa nem sem [ ] nem com [ ].

Não obstante , o motivo da pergunta é saber se há alguma especificação contra ou algum jeito de fazer rodar com ponto nos nomes das colunas

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT [col.A] FROM stabela UNION SELECT DISTINCT [col.B] FROM stabela UNION SELECT DISTINCT [col.C] FROM stabela");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $nome=$row['col.A'];
    }
```

> Warning:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ....... on line 58
>
> A linha 58 é  (while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))

Comment: Não seria `\`Col.A\``,  `\`Col.B\``,  `\`Col.C\``, ao invés de entre `[ ]`?

Comment: ja tentou apelido? tipo [col.A] as colunaA, [col.B] as colunab..?

Comment: Inkeliz é isso mesmo, funcionou!! O negócio é colocar entre aspas invertidas (a crase do nosso teclado).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou postar aqui a solução encontrada que achei no Guia de Estudo para Certificação MySQL e também na documentação recomendada pelo nosso amigo Anderson Carlos Woss [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

Coloque os nomes das colunas na query entre aspas simples invertidas.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `col.A` FROM stabela UNION SELECT DISTINCT `col.B` FROM stabela UNION SELECT DISTINCT `col.C` FROM stabela");
```

Essa aspas invertidas nada mais são que o acento crase do seu teclado. Shift + tecla acento e tecla espaço. Fiz o teste no DB e rodou redondinho :)

Comment: Tem tudo explicado aqui na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html), caso queira adicionar à resposta.

Comment: A comunidade ser em português não exclui a possibilidade de você utilizar referências em inglês. Principalmente quando é a documentação oficial da ferramenta que está utilizando. Quanto ao ponto, verás, se ler: *Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000*. *Quoted identifiers* são identificadores entre crases, como utilizou na sua resposta.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, faz referência a colocar aspas para identificadores que sejam palavras reservadas  mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100; que não é o caso de nomes de colunas com ponto. Nomes de colunas com ponto não são palavras reservadas ou nome de funções.

Comment: *If an identifier **contains special characters** or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it.*, apenas dei a dica para você embasar sua resposta em uma referência confiável. Isso aumentaria muito a confiabilidade da mesma. Você coloca a referência se quiser,

Comment: Vi vários sites falando de caracteres especias, mas nenhum deles se referiu ao ponto.

Comment: Então basta ler o tópico anterior "Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers" e verás que somente é permitido `[0-9,a-z,A-Z$_]`, não incluindo o ponto.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou tirar os colchetes?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    col.A
FROM stabela 

UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    col.B
FROM stabela 

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    col.C
FROM stabela
```

Comment: Essa foi a primeira tentativa!

Comment: Voce precisa saber qual resultado veio de cada coluna?

Comment: poderia tentar:

SELECT DISTINCT 
    col,
    'A' as coluna
FROM stabela 

UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT 
   col,
   'B' as coluna
FROM stabela 

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    col,
    'C' as coluna
FROM stabela

Comment: Entendo. Acredito que o problema seja o nome da coluna utilizando "."
Tenta substituir o ponto por _

veja esse artigo acho que vai ajuda-lo
http://www.devmedia.com.br/padronizacao-de-nomenclatura-revista-sql-magazine-100/24710